# Java : Program to check if entered number is a SUPER Number or not.. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, function, while-loop, boolean, logic

So.. This is the code. A 'Super' number is one in which the sum of the digits, which are raised in accordance with their position, equals the number itself.

TLDR:

input : 175

1^1 + 7^2 + 5^3 = 175

Output : Super number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Models_Q6 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int num=s.nextInt();
    int count=1;
    while(num>0){
        num%=10;
        count++;
    }       
    Models_Q6 k=new Models_Q6 ();
    k.Super(num,count);
    boolean check=k.Super(num,count);
    if(check==true)
        System.out.println("The entered number is a Super number");
    else
        System.out.println("The entered number is not a Super number");

}
boolean Super(int num,int count){
int test=num;
int a=0,sum=0;
while(num>0){
a=num%10;
num/=10;
count--;
sum+= Math.pow(a, count);
}
if(sum==test)
return true ;
else 
return false;




}

}
```

I ran this program through Eclipse and I do get it to work after it accepts the number. And other logic to do the program would be appreciated.

P.S I need the coding to be done in a function called 'boolean Super(int)' Cause Professor says so ._.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you asking here? You say that you did get it to work, so what is the problem? (Also remember that your professor may have rules about what help you can get form others; Stack Overflow users may give you answers that tell you too much about how to solve the assignment, which in turn may make *you* responsible for cheating)

Comment: @EmilVikström All the program does is accept a number, then it does nothing.

Comment: You can upvote the correct answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(num>0){
    num%=10;
    count++;
}
```

If `count` is what you made to count digits, this shall not.

```
while(num>0){
    num/=10; //CHANGE
    count++;
}
```

This will.